# Is predefined query more efficient than ad-hoc SQL query using ADO.NET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader, datareader

We have a table `CroppedImage` which has `Id`, `PosX`, `PosY`, `Width`, `Heigth` columns with datatype of `tinyint` and another column `CroppedPicture` with datatype of `varbinary`.

Here is ad-hoc way :

```
List<int> GetList = GetTopNecessaryImages();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    com.CommandText = "select * from CroppedImage where Id=" + GetList[i];
    using (SqlDataReader objSqlDtReader = com.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        while(objSqlDtReader.Read()) 
        {
             CropImage objCrop = new CropImage ();
             CropImage.Img = (objSqlDtReader["CroppedPicture"]);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is predefined query with parameters.

```
List<int> GetList = GetTopNecessaryImages();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    com.CommandText = "select * from CroppedImage where Id=@IdPar";
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPar", GetList[i]);
    using (SqlDataReader objSqlDtReader = com.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
        while(objSqlDtReader.Read()) 
        {
             CropImage objCrop = new CropImage (); 
             CropImage.Img = (objSqlDtReader["CroppedPicture"]);
        }
    }
}
```

`Image` field is less than 250KB.
I have tested both of them and saw no difference on my machine however the database administrator tells me that ad-hoc queries eats more memory than predefined one on server which host SQL.
Is this true ? Does this two options have any kind of difference on performance ?

Comment: The reality is that your DBA is not correct. These are BOTH ad-hoc queries. Ad-hoc queries get an execution plan created for them and they are cached just like the execution plan for a stored procedure. The second method is prefered because you are using parameterized queries and preventing sql injection. What I do see though is you are using AddWithValue. This should be avoided as it sometimes it gets it wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: What your DBA means could be, that a "predefined" (=precompiled) VIEW (or Stored Procedure or Table Valued Function) doesn't have to be compiled. But such a simple query is fast in any case... (at least if there is an index on "Id" ;-)   )

Comment: And even if your DBA means stored proc or a view that doesn't mean it is magically going to be faster. They all boil down to creating (or reusing if it exists) an execution plan.

Comment: As you said these images are small and you selecting them one at a time. There is little in the way of ram consumption for a 250k image that is sent along. As soon as the query executes sql server will throw it away. Honestly I think the biggest issue is your doing this process RBAR. You should pull all the data you need in one pass instead of querying over and over. That would ease the pressure on the sql box significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your DBA is correct, though the terminology is a bit confusing.  It's more a question of parameterized queries vs. non-parameterized queries.

In the case of a parameterized query (`"select * from CroppedImage where Id=@IdPar"`), even if you execute this query multiple times with different parameters, the query only needs to be parsed and compiled once by SQL Server.  Any subsequent executions of the query will reuse the same query plan from cache.

In contrast, a non-parameterized query (`"select * from CroppedImage where Id=" + GetList[i]`) will be treated as a completely distinct query every time it is executed with a different `GetList[i]` value.  In this case, the query will be parsed and recompiled on the SQL Server every single time.  And this will consume more memory, as the database server now has to cache multiple query plans instead of a single one.

For small amounts of queries, the difference will not be noticeable.  But as soon as you have large transaction volume, you may start noticing an effect on both speed and memory.

Here is an interesting article that provides more details on the matter: [Use SQL Parameters to Overcome Ad Hoc Performance Issues](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16994/Use-SQL-Parameters-to-Overcome-Ad-Hoc-Performance).

Answer (score 1):

The reality is that your DBA is not correct. These are BOTH ad-hoc queries. Ad-hoc queries get an execution plan created for them and they are cached just like the execution plan for a stored procedure. The second method is prefered because you are using parameterized queries and preventing sql injection. What I do see though is you are using AddWithValue. This should be avoided as it sometimes it gets it wrong.